# Transforming a 2D Mesh into a 3D object

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

So I have A 2D Mesh Region, for example

```
MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}, {Polygon[{1, 2, 5}], Polygon[{6, 2, 5}], Polygon[{6, 2, 7}], Polygon[{2, 7, 3}], Polygon[{3, 4, 7}], Polygon[{4, 7, 8}], Polygon[{4, 8, 5}], Polygon[{1, 4, 5}]}]
```

and a point named point A `Point[{0,0,5}]`.
Now what I want to do is to "pull" the 2D mesh towards the point, creating a 3D mesh area. Each point of the original 2D mesh is moved towards based on its distance to point A, with a fixed ratio, so that the new 3D object would look like this:

[image: ect]

with all the z coordinates of the original 2D mesh to be 0.
But how? I found it really hard to create the new faces in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found an application for the `Prism` primitive:

```
M = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 
     2}, {1, 2}}, {Polygon[{1, 2, 5}], Polygon[{6, 2, 5}], 
    Polygon[{6, 2, 7}], Polygon[{2, 7, 3}], Polygon[{3, 4, 7}], 
    Polygon[{4, 7, 8}], Polygon[{4, 8, 5}], Polygon[{1, 4, 5}]}];

p = {0, 0, 5};
x = MeshCoordinates[M];
n = Length[x];
x = Join[x, ConstantArray[0., {n, 1}], 2];
t = 0.5;
y = t ConstantArray[p, n] + (1 - t) x;
triangles = MeshCells[M, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
prisms = Join[triangles, triangles + n, 2];
M1 = MeshRegion[Join[x, y], Prism[prisms]]
```

[image]

So, this `MeshRegion` consists of `Prism`s. If you prefer a `Tetrahedron`-based mesh, just apply `DiscretizeRegion` to `M1`.

Comment: Wow! This is an amazing approach. The elegance of the prisms is beyond what I'd thought to be a solution.